# How can I transform TSX source code to TS code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, tsx

Essentially, I'm wanting the behavior provided by [@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx), but preserving all types, other TS language features, ESNext syntax, comments, etc. (I simply want to transform the TypeScript XML-formatted code into plain TypeScript using the specified JSX-factory function (e.g. `React.createElement` / `jsx` / bring-your-own / etc.)

```typescriptreact
// in
let name: any = 'world';
const div = <div>hello {name as string}</div>;
```

```typescript
// out (classic runtime)
let name: any = 'world';
const div = React.createElement('div', null, 'hello ', name as string);

// out (automatic runtime)
let name: any = 'world';
const div = _jsxs('div', { children: ['hello ', name as string] });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your'e misunderstanding the concept of typescript usage. We only use typescript in development for a solid schema based approach. On running the build command your typescript code gets coverted into javascript code and all associated typescript features are removed. So bacically we run javascript in production.

What I've understood is that you want to preserve behavior provided by @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx along with accociated typescript types with it on compiling the typescript code. However in my opinion that's not possible because typescript compiler would only convert typescript code to js, discarding all types.

Comment: If what OP's wanting is possible, it definitely wouldn't be done with `tsc`, it'd require some other sort of build tool. I am curious if @jsejcksn could provide any more context for _why_ what you're requesting would be useful/how you intend to use it? If you're shipping a library, it should be safe to either ship raw TS and require that users transpile it, or compile all the way down to JS, as @waleed-tariq suggests.

Comment: If what you are wanting to do is export the generated TypeScript as a library, note that the combination of generated .js and .d.ts file are effectively equivalent to the original source - all of the type information is preserved in the type declaration files; it's not as easy for a human to read, but generally the tools that accept typescript sources will accept declaration files just as easily.